# unset memory error in wordpress on wamp

Tags: php, wordpress, garbage-collection, garbage

**Error Allowed memory size of xxxxxxxxxx bytes exhausted (tried to allocate xxxxxxxx bytes)**
 I am new to php.memory_get_usage()

Initial: 61770528 bytes Final: 65964896 bytes Peak: 71564920 bytes 
The short answer i got is that references are merely a way for two variables to share the same value and unset() only deletes a variable, not a value.

So,
where to put unset($var); or $var = null
Do not want to increase memory limit

Using wordpress theme with some heavy plugins.Kindly overlook mt poor english :]
 got a code but where to place it
       The change was adding single line of code:

```
public function run()
{   
  gc_disable();
```

Comment: Why did you disable the garbage collector?

Comment: Checking runtime but NO results rather dropped.

Comment: Most often, the answer to running out of memory is not to change how much memory is being used, but rather find out *why* you're running out of memory. I've seen that the best way to remove a variable completely is to set it to null, then unset it, once you are completely done with that variable.

Comment: Then you probably need to increase the memory limit for the runtime checks only. That'll give you an indication of how much memory the gc saves and how much time it costs.

Comment: used this as reference too  http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2014/12/what-about-garbage.html

Comment: The blog author himself states that you shouldn't disable garbage collection in all your code, but rather that there are edge cases when it might be useful. I agree with that. A few other things caught my eye while glancing through the blog. The author underestimated the changes in PHP7 (zvals no longer store a refcount, but the internal values do. References are handled differently.). He also suggests improvements that cost a lot, and gain very little. E.g. he wants to double the size of the root buffer in certain situations, without mentioning that the entire thing would need to be copied ..

Comment: So what you would suggest.any function that can be written for function file